# Storing true or false into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've compiled a list of 'old browsers'. I'm doing a check on each one to see if they are in the HTTP_USER_AGENT. My results keep storing as true in the array even when they're false.

My problem appeared when I started storing the results of the true or false test in the array. This makes me think the problem is there.

I echo the $result and it is 1 in all cases. i would expect it to be zero when not true.

The code is below (I've cut down the list to just check if the browser is IE or Safari in this example):

```
<?php
function checkIfThisIsAnOldBrowser()
{
$userBrowserInfo = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

/**********Unsupported Browsers List****************************/
// Internet Exlporer
$oldBrowserCheck['MSIE']=strpos($userBrowserInfo, 'MSIE') ? true : false;//All Internet Explorer

// Safari
$oldBrowserCheck['safari']=strpos($userBrowserInfo, 'Safari') ? true : false;// All Safari
//END OF LIST

foreach($oldBrowserCheck as $browserName=>$result)
  {
    if($result=1){echo "<div class=\"oldBrowserWarning\"><h1>OLD BROWSER DETECTED: $browserName $result</h1></div>";}
  }

}//end of function
checkIfThisIsAnOldBrowser();
?>
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($result=1)
```

Should be

```
if ($result == 1)
```

or

```
if ($result == true)
```

or even just

```
if ($result)
```

Comment: wow! it must be late....school boy error. thanks matt.

Comment: @matt the last one, will enter the statement if it's even set.. Regardless if it's true OR false

Comment: That's not so. Doing if ($result) is exactly the same as if ($result == true). Check out the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php